# PHP format text after strip_tags()

Tags: php, formatting

I'm parsing an html text to get the plain text with strip_tags() and works really fine. But the resulting text has not spaces after commas and dots

Example of result:
**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur...adipiscing elit.**

How can I turn that, to this:
**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur... Adipiscing elit.**

I think to use

```
str_replace(',', ', ', $text);
```

But to detect one or multiple dots i don't think this is the best solution. Is any way to convert to upper case the first letter after a dot?

I'm searching for a function to format the text but cant get lucky.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to uppercase after a dot

```
function sentence_case($string) {
    $sentences = preg_split('/([.?!]+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $new_string = '';
    foreach ($sentences as $key => $sentence) {
        $new_string .= ($key & 1) == 0?
            ucfirst(strtolower(trim($sentence))) :
            $sentence.' ';
    }
    return trim($new_string);
}

print sentence_case('HMM. WOW! WHAT?');

// Outputs: "Hmm. Wow! What?"
```